# Apache Cordova Command Not Found Mac El Capitan

Tags: macos, cordova, osx-elcapitan

I've just tried installing Cordova several times using:

[image]

Whenever I type `cordova` into the command line it says `command not found`

I ran

```
$ sudo find / -name cordova 2> /dev/null
```

which returned:

```
/private/tmp/npm-6328-0567a7f3/registry.npmjs.org/cordova
/Users/userDirectory/.npm/cordova
/Users/userDirectory/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/cordova
/usr/local/bin/cordova
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova
```

I added:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/share/npm
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/
/usr/local/share/npm/bin
/.npm
.npm
/Users/userDirectory/.npm
/Users/userDirectory/.npm/registry.npmjs.org
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src
```

to the `etc/paths` file and still get the same error.

Please help.

Comment: What does `npm root` and `npm root -g` return?

Comment: @Shawn Did you installed cordova globally using -g option?

Comment: npm root returns -bash: npm: command not found.

Comment: Yes, I used the -g option. :)